# What is a function client?

Tags: c++, function, compilation, inline

I just read in "C++ How to Program" 10th Edition that "if you change the definition of an inline function, you must recompile all of that function's clients." What is a client? I've been poring over the Internet and all I could find were web pages explaining how to set up servers. . . What is the definition of a function client?

Comment: It's other functions/classes/definitions/files that use that function.

Answer (score 2):

By *"clients"*, the book means source files (technically: translation units) that include the definition.

> I've been poring over the Internet and all I could find ...

The book appears to use the word client in an abstract, descriptive sense. Their usage is quite untypical, so it'll not be likely to find much similar usage on the net.

> What is the definition of a function client?

There is no such technical term. You know what a function is, I hope. A client is a user. Therefore "function client" describes something that uses the function.

Answer (score 2):

> if you change the definition of an inline function, you must recompile all of that function's clients." What is a client?

The other functions, classes, definitions, header or source files that *use* this function.